# Batch file - using multiple IF's to separate

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing, cmd

I am writing a batch script what i am looking for is something so that multiple hings be compared with each other

for example i have to look into folders to check what all files are there if there are following files

```
  abc.wxs
  verify.wxs
  start.wxs
  myname.wxs
```

i want to go to

```
 makeadmin
```

else if there are

```
  abc.wxs
  verify.wxs
  start.wxs
  myname.wxs
  verifyme.wxs
  abc.dll
```

i have written some thing like

```
IF EXIST "abc.wxs" (
IF EXIST "verify.wxs" (
IF EXIST "start.wxs" (
IF EXIST "myname.wxs" (
goto makeadmin
) else (
echo 1
 )
 ) else (
 echo 2
)
) else (
echo 3
)    
) else (
echo 4
)
```

Now how do i integrate the second part

Comment: The logic of your question makes no sense. You say you want to implement logic like `"if A then x else if A & B then y"`. But `A & B` can only be true if `A` is true. The second condition can never execute! If the first IF is false, then so is the second IF false. If the first IF is true, then the second IF may be true, but it will never execute because of the ELSE. Also, you need to learn to accept  the best answer that solves your question by clicking on the check mark near the upper left corner of the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a "checking buffer". I mean each file will count +1 to the check variable. Now, if the sum matches the number of checked files it would do something specific.
Take a look below :

```
@echo off
set sum=0

IF EXIST "abc.wxs" (
set /a sum=%sum%+1
)
IF EXIST "verify.wxs" (
set /a sum=%sum%+1
)
IF EXIST "start.wxs" (
set /a sum=%sum%+1
)
IF EXIST "myname.wxs" (
set /a sum=%sum%+1
)
IF EXIST "verifyme.wxs" (
set /a sum=%sum%+1
)
IF EXIST "abc.dll" (
set /a sum=%sum%+1
)

if sum==4 (
set sum=0
goto makeadmin
)
if sum==6 (
set sum=0
<insert whatever you want here>
)

pause
```

Generally, I find it quite useful to use counters with numbers. It's much more convenient for me. I hope it helps.

**P.S.** I am setting sum=0 on each case of the 2 "if"s because I haven't tested this (cause I am on linux right now) and I am afraid that if you return to the beginning of the program, you'll going to have the sum over-exceed the number 6.

**EDIT**
The above can be shortened and made easier to maintain by using a FOR loop. Also, the `set sum=0` is not needed within the IFs. Finally, variables do not need to be expanded within SET /A. `set /a sum=sum+1` works, as does `set /a sum+=1`

```
@echo off
set sum=0
for %%F in (
  abc.wxs
  verify.wxs
  start.wxs
  myname.wxs
  verifyme.wxs
  abc.dll
) do if exist %%F set /a sum+=1
if sum==4 goto makeadmin
if sum==6 REM do something else
```

Comment: +1, Technically not what the OP asked for, but the logic of the OP's question makes no sense. I like your interpretation of the OP's intent. I've taken the liberty to edit your answer to show how it can be shortened and made easier to maintain.